# Can you help understanding how the OR operator works in this code?

Tags: python

The first code example prints "True" but the second code example prints "False".
They're both the same thing or not?

This prints "True":

```
print("f" == ("f" or "t"))
```

This prints "False"

```
print(False == (False or True))
```

Comment: try to print inner expressions only and see what it says

Comment: `False or True` returns `True`. `"f" or "t"` returns `"f"`, since `bool("f")` is `True`.

Comment: `"f"` and `"t"` as strings.  `True` and `False` are special boolean values with special values of truthiness.  Why would the behave the same in a boolean expression as two strings?

Comment: Please make the title more informative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brief explanation of how the OR operator works in Python:

> With the Boolean OR operator, you can connect two Boolean expressions
> into one compound expression. At least one subexpressions must be true
> for the compound expression to be considered true, and it doesn’t
> matter which. If both subexpressions are false, then the expression is
> false.

If you want to understand in a more pratical way please try this code:

```
print(False or True)
```

**Output**

```
True
```

For this reason your final statement would be:

```
print(False == True)
```

**Output**

```
False
```

[Source](https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/)